# wxPython set selected control upon application start

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simple wxPython application. It basically has a image and a text-entry field (a `wx.TextCtrl`).

I want to be able to immediately be able to start entering text as soon as the window opens. Right now, I have to first click in the text control, and then I can start entering text.

Here is a minimal app that demonstrates the issue:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """ We simply derive a new class of Frame. """
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))

        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        mainSizer.Add(self.control, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

I've poked around with `wx.SetInsertionPoint`, but that does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, derp. I had to look further up the inheritance chain.

You can simply call `SetFocus()` on the control (in this case, `self.control.SetFocus()`).

`SetFocus()` is a member function of wxWindow. I was only looking at the docs for wxTextCtrl.

---

Of course, I didn't think to look up the inheritance chain until I had already asked the question.

I'm leaving this here, as this is a pretty hard to google issue. Hopefully this will help someone else.